# Practical convergence in $C^{\infty}_c$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

Let $C^{\infty}_c$ be the space of $C^{\infty}$ functions with compact support in $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology derived by the convergence in infinity norm in every $C^{k}_c$. I would like to proof that for any $\varphi\in C^{\infty}_c$, then $$\frac{\varphi(tx)-\varphi(x)}{t-1}\rightarrow x\varphi'(x)$$ when $t\rightarrow 1$, where the limit it has to be considered in $C_c^{\infty}$.

How to do?

Comment: It basically suffices to show the convergence in $C^0_c$, once you use the fact that $(x\varphi')^{(n)} = n \varphi^{(n)} + x \varphi^{(n+1)}$ and that $(\varphi(tx))^{(n)} = (t^n - 1)\varphi^{(n)}(tx) + \varphi^{(n)}(tx)$. The convergence in $C^0$ should follow from the pointwise convergence and the pointwise convergence at the level of the first derivative + compactness.

Comment: But the convergence has to be uniform! It's not true that pointwise convergence and the pointwise convergence at the level of the first derivative + compactness= uniform congergence.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: let $h=t-1$, if $x\neq 0$
$$\frac{\varphi(tx)-\varphi(x)}{t-1}=x\frac{\varphi(x+hx)-\varphi(x)}{hx}.$$
By mean value theorem 
$\varphi(x+hx)-\varphi(x) = \varphi'(\eta)hx $, where $\eta\in [\min\{x,x+hx\}, \max\{x,x+hx\}]$. 
Again by mean value theorem
$$|x||\varphi'(\eta)-\varphi'(x)|\leq |x(\eta-x)| \sup_y |\varphi''(y)| \leq |x^2h| \sup_y |\varphi''(y)|  \to0,\qquad \forall x\in supp(\varphi) $$ 
since $|\eta-x|\leq |hx|$, $|x^2|$ is bounded due to compact support, $\sup_y |\varphi''(y)|$ is bounded since it is  $C_c^\infty$.

This argument can be repeated for all higher order derivatives.

Comment: I don't understand the help

Comment: Use the substitution $h=t-1$, you have $\lim_{t\to 1}\frac{\varphi(tx)-\varphi(x)}{t-1}=x \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\varphi(x+hx)-\varphi(x)}{hx},$ where the last limit is the definition of derivative

Comment: @Milly: your proof works pointwise. But it is possible that the OP wanted an argument showing convergence in the $C^\infty_0$ topology.

Comment: The limit is pointwise, I want a limit in $C^{\infty}_c$.

Comment: Ok, I did not get it at first.

Comment: "This argument can be repeated for all higher order derivatives.". I think it's not so obvious but Willie Wong explained it well in his other comment.